# Set the button to Done instead of Go in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, imeoptions

I'm trying to switch the button in the softkey from "Go" to "Done" and vice-versa.
If I just set the imeoption

```
private fun showDoneOnSoftKeyboard() {
    setImeOptionsOnSoftKeyboard(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
}

private fun showGoOnSoftKeyboard() {
    setImeOptionsOnSoftKeyboard(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO)
}

private fun setImeOptionsOnSoftKeyboard(imeOptions: Int) {
    contractIdInput.imeOptions = imeOptions
}
```

the button is not changed. I've found that by doing:

```
private fun setImeOptionsOnSoftKeyboard(imeOptions: Int) {
    val inputType = contractIdInput.inputType
    contractIdInput.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL
    contractIdInput.imeOptions = imeOptions
    contractIdInput.inputType = inputType
}
```

the button is changed. The problem is though that the keyboard settings are reset that means that if I have for example the capslock set after I switch between states (for example from *Done* to *Go*) then the capslock is reset.

I have also tried

```
contractIdInput.imeOptions = imeOptions
val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
imm.restartInput(contractIdInput)
```

but this has the same effect.

I tried this one as well:

```
contractIdInput.setImeActionLabel("Custom text", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
```

but it does not work either.

Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: Have you try with android:imeOptions property in xml ?

Comment: But I need to change it dinamically

Comment: it may be device-specific (actually keyboard-app-specific). Some keyboard apps ignore this.

Comment: In some way it is but at the same time it isn't because it happens on too many devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this can't be done. The IME-options are thought to be set statically in the XML or programmatically but they can't be modified dynamically while the user is typing.